# Ruby and Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am looking to write a web application using `RoR` for the backend and `Backbone` for the front-end. The Web app will have to list all the member documents.

Does anyone have any experience with running RoR and Backbone.js? How can we call **REST API** of RoR using the Backbone.js.

Comment: This might be useful to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918586/rails-and-backbone-working-together/11922573#11922573

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649666/rails-vs-backbone-who-should-be-responsible-for-templates-and-views/12657995#12657995