# Backbone JS and Rails: Trial Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am completely new to Backbone.js (have only studied the documentation) and was wondering if it's possible to test its functionality with maybe a Controller or two in a Rails app? I have some functionality I would love to build into my existing application that could highly benefit from backbone, but I am just wanting to "test the waters" with Backbone in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Rails, but that would definitely be possible. The best way to play around with Backbone for a small piece would be to add a new Backbone view to your app. Leave an element in your app that you can tack on a Backbone View with and play around with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I found this tutorial: http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/08/28/a-basic-rails-and-backbone-js-example.html.. I am going to dig into it now

Comment: If you decide to dig in deeper, here's an open source book on Backbone: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/ My buddy is a Rails developer, and he really liked these videos, though only the first 3 are free: http://www.backbonerails.com/

Comment: Also have a look at this book by thoughtbot, much recommended: https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails . And on some challenges of combining the two frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918586/rails-and-backbone-working-together